# onchange select do different mysql query without refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

All options of the following `select` element are from a database:

```
<select id="list" name="list">
  <option>Mercedes-Benz</option>
  <option>Ford</option>
  <option>Fiat</option>
</select>
```

I need help with `onchange`. I have a `select` element, and I need to do different MySQL queries when I choose something from select list. Example:

When I select **Mercedes-Benz**, it would do this:

```
$query = "SELECT shortinfo FROM `table` WHERE type = 'Mercedes-Benz'";
```

And if I choose **Ford**, it would do

```
$query = "SELECT shortinfo FROM `table` WHERE type = 'Ford'";
```

and so on.

Then I need to display the result in a textarea under the list, for example:

```
<textarea rows="7" cols="90">Mercedes-Benz is a German automobile manufacturer,
  a multinational division of the German manufacturer Daimler AG. The brand is
  used for luxury automobiles, buses, coaches, and trucks. Mercedes-Benz is 
  headquartered in Stuttgart, Baden-Württemberg, Germany.</textarea>
```

Comment: Do you know what AJAX is?

Comment: You can simply use jQuery Ajax for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to rely on Ajax. Just add a onchange attribute to the select list. Then have it call a JavaScript function. Have the function call a remote php file to make you request (This will happen without a page refresh). Make it return your request results to your HTML page. I will give a better answer later but I'm on a phone right now. The easiest way to make an Ajax request is to use jquery.